# Remote development in Pycharm - without local copies

Tags: pycharm

I know how to set up the Remote Interpreter in Pycharm and so far remote developing went well.

In some cases though, I cannot hold local copies of the files on the machine I work on for commercial issues.

Is there a way, to develop remotely in Pycharm *WITHOUT* having local copies of the scripts and other project files?

Comment: problem here is pycharm debugger is galaxies away vscode

Comment: The only reason I don't use VSCode is because debugging in PyCharm is indeed galaxies far ahead

Comment: [This is the corresponding feature request for PyCharm.](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-19752)

Answer (score 12):

I just had a similar problem. So far, I found two possibilities to open remote files with PyCharm:

**1. Use sshfs to mount remote directory**

Like this, the directory will be listed when you browse the files your local computer with PyCharm.
That is described e.g. here: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-sshfs-to-mount-remote-file-systems-over-ssh

 I was not able to try this solution myself because I don't have sshfs installed and no root priviliges.

**2. Use the new PyCharm feature**

In PyCharm, just go to `Tools - Deployment - Browse Remote Host` as described here:
https://blog.jetbrains.com/pycharm/2015/06/feature-spotlight-editing-remote-files/ 
and add your server. 

Choosing `SFTP` as connection type and using the already existing private key file for key-pair authentication worked for me.

Comment: I am using #2 now... I have high hopes for this library tho -https://github.com/jupyterlab/jupyterlab. Waiting for its official beta